# Teamcity restore a deleted build configuration

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-9.0

Is there a way in teamcity to restore a deleted build configuration. I found [Restore just deleted project](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/How+To...#HowTo...-RestoreJustDeletedProject) which is about restoring a deleted project but can't find any information about restoring a deleted build configuration. I am using Teamcity 8.0.6

Answer (score 6):

TeamCity 9, locate your data directory and you'll find a trash folder, like so:

`D:\TeamCity\Data\config\_trash`

Take a copy of the whole thing to some other folder, just in case.

Move the effected project folders from `config\_trash` to `config\projects`.

Remove the suffixed `.projectNN` from each project folder.

You may see critical errors in the main web portal while this is happening.

Restart TeamCity just for good measure.

[image: Suffixes]

Comment: Note: since this mess-up, I enabled storing config in Git which took all of 3 minutes to setup and is well-recommended.

Comment: I accidentally deleted a whole project and its build configurations, and this is exactly what I did to recover it; I found that the project didn't reappear until I had restarted the service, so I suspect it's a mandatory step rather than a "just for good measure".

Answer (score 2):

The previous versions of build configuration setting are stored in [/config/projects/buildTypes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Data+Directory#TeamCityDataDirectory-StructureofTeamCityDataDirectory) folder in different *.xml.N files. To restore setting replace *.xml file with *.xml.N file. 
Also since **TeamCity 9** it is possible to [store all project setting in VCS](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control).

Comment: This will probably help in restoring the changed settings. I don't think it keeps files for deleted build configurations. All xml files related to a build are deleted as soon as we delete the build configuration.

Comment: You are right. It is not possible to restore deleted build configuration. We have the related request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-34774, please vote. However [Version Settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control) feature is present to solve this problem.

Comment: Already voted there. Apart from version settings, we can restore it from a backup as well. The back up one will work in Teamcity 8 as well.

Comment: We were just able to do this with TC9. Deleted build configurations are stored for 24 hours according to their documentation (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/How+To...#HowTo...-RestoreJustDeletedProject), although we have some really old ones--maybe the TTL for trashes can be changed. You can restore by going to <TeamCity Data Directory>/config/_trash and moving the <project name>.projectN directory back to <TeamCity Data Directory>/config/projects and removing the `.projectN` part.

Comment: @ sixstringtheory Not talking about restoring Projects. I am talking about Build Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, available since 9.0 is to place project settings in version control (Git, Mercurial, or Subversion and Perforce since 9.1), and then restore removed files using VCS commands.